# Skip amount of characters to downloading data from flat file

Tags: ssis, package, flat-file

I have a flat file which consists a line(when I look through the Excel) and some amount of characters when I open it with Notapad.

How to skip this INFO string and begin download data after this line.

There is my line on skreen.
[image]

I use SSIS package to download data from file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the flat file connection manager? If so double click flat file connection manager, go to the preview page there is an option to allow you to skip certain number of ahead rows

Comment: Yes, I am using Flat Connection Manager and I did that poion in the package. But still downloaded 0 rows.

Comment: try to use Notepad++ to open the file (enable 'show all symbols' option in view), try to find what is column and row delimiter, and change the delimiter option for both in flat file connection manager. I am guessing the format is the reason that the skiprows does not work

Comment: usually the row delimiter is **{LF}{CR}**, if so, specify it for row delimiter in flat file connection manager, and then skip 1st line, should be good this time.